# How bind fragment in activity (from xml)?

Tags: butterknife

In my xml I have fragment:

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/brandDetailsFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/brandBottomContainer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/brandDetailsToolBar" />
```

in my activity:

```
public class BrandDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView((R.id.brandDetailsFragment))
    BrandDetailsFragment brandDetailsFragment;

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.brand_details_activity);
            ButterKnife.bind(this);
        }
```

But I get error (on runtime):

```
e: BrandDetailsActivity.java:29: error: @BindView fields must extend from View or be an interface. (com.myproject.android.customer.ui.BrandDetailsActivity.brandDetailsFragment)
e: 

e:     BrandDetailsFragment brandDetailsFragment;
e:                          ^
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
```

I know that **fragment** is not extend **View**. But I need bind fragment in activity. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

you should add fragment to activity like this, because activity add fragment `getSupportFragmentManager`

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = mFm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(fragment);
    ft.commit();
```